# adding data from one df conditionally in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
test_data = pd.DataFrame(np.array([np.arange(10)]*3).T, columns =['issuer_id','winner_id','gov'])


    issuer_id   winner_id   gov
0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2
3   3   3   3
4   4   4   4
5   5   5   5
6   6   6   6
7   7   7   7
8   8   8   8
9   9   9   9
```

and a list of two-tuples consisting of a dataframe and a label encoding 'gov' (perhaps a label:dataframe dict would be better). In test_out below the two labels are 2 and 7.

```
test_out = [(pd.DataFrame(np.array([np.arange(10)]*2).T, columns =['id','partition']),2),(pd.DataFrame(np.array([np.arange(10)]*2).T, columns =['id','partition']),7)]

[(   id  partition
  0   0          0
  1   1          1
  2   2          2
  3   3          3
  4   4          4
  5   5          5
  6   6          6
  7   7          7
  8   8          8
  9   9          9, 2), (   id  partition
  0   0          0
  1   1          1
  2   2          2
  3   3          3
  4   4          4
  5   5          5
  6   6          6
  7   7          7
  8   8          8
  9   9          9, 7)]
```

I want to add two columns to the test_data dataframe: issuer_partition and winner_partition

```
test_data['issuer_partition']=''
test_data['winner_partition']=''
```

and I would like to fill in these values from the test_out list where the entry in the gov column determines the labeled dataframe in test_out to draw from. Then I look up the winner_id and issuer_id in the id-partition dataframe and write them into test_data.

Put another way: I have a list of labeled dataframes that I would like to loop through to conditionally fill in data in a primary dataframe.

Is there a clever way to use merge in this scenario?

*edit - added another sentence and fixed test_out code

Comment: Your `test_out` construction code does not run, please fix and show desired output and the input dfs

Comment: very sorry about that - after a few edits I hope its readable.

Comment: It's terribly unclear to me what you are trying to achieve can you simplify this significantly, I don't see how you're distinguishing which df in your test_out list to lookup when the gov values match both dfs in test_out's ids and partition, none of what you've written makes much sense to me, what does the 2 and 7 signify here?

Comment: So I've now read that the 2 and 7 represent the gov id's you could've used a dict rather than a list with tuples to perform this lookup. It would be easier to have gov be a real column and have a dataframe that had all the values in and then merge on gov to fill in the values you want